# How to make checklist in UITableView - Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I made an app with `UITableView`. I want to show a tick mark in the left when cell is touched, and to be hidden when again is touched. I used some code and It's not showing as I wanted. The tick is showing on the right not on the left of screen.

**This is how I want to make:**
[image]

**This is how it is:**
[image]

And here is code that I used:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.myTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
}
```

In conclusion, first problem is that the tick is showing on the right of the cell and not on the left. And the other problem, it won't untick (hide when cell is pressed again)

Thanks.

Comment: Try this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableMultiSelect/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: You have to use images and changes images in cellforrow delegate method

Comment: @Sudhir this tutorial is in Obj-C.

Comment: @AhmadIshfaq I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you come on skype and show me what you did??

Comment: @AhmadIshfaq Ya. Till now I was working on that answer below and it's not working.

Comment: I will be online in about 2 hours on skype.Than i can help you, sounds good??

Comment: Alright, can we talk somewhere else ? Because I don't use skype.

Comment: Can you install skype because i need to see your code to help you

Comment: How about google hangout did you use that??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112180/discussion-between-ahmad-ishfaq-and-emi).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
        let cellIdentifier = "DhikrTableViewCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GoalsTableViewCell

        cell.tickButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GoalsViewController.toggleSelcted(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        cell.tickButton.tag = indexPath.row
        // Fetches the appropriate meal for the data source layout.
        let workout = workouts[indexPath.row]
        let number = numbers[indexPath.row]

        if workout.isSelected {
            cell.tickButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Ticked Button"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        } else {
            cell.tickButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Tick Button"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }

        cell.nameLabel.text = workout.name
        cell.numberLabel.text = number.number

        return cell
    }

func toggleSelcted(button: UIButton) {
        let workout = workouts[button.tag]
        workout.isSelected = !workout.isSelected
        myTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this behavior with default UITableViewCell, you may need to set table view to edit mode.

Try the following code in your viewDidLoad.

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated: false)
```

This will show tick mark on the left side, and also this will untick (hide) when cell is pressed again.

Edited:
If you need more customization, Create a custom table view cell and handle the selection/tick mark manually.

This will be your cell.swift.

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tickImageView: UIImageView!

//Handles the cell selected state
var checked: Bool! {
    didSet {
        if (self.checked == true) {
            self.tickImageView.image = UIImage(named: "CheckBox-Selected")
        }else{
            self.tickImageView.image = UIImage(named: "CheckBox-Normal")
        }
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    checked = false
    self.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
}
```

The datasource array is,

```
let list = ["Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 2", "Title 4"]
```

The view controller didLoad will be like

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    listView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "OptionsSelectionCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "SelectionCell")
}
```

The view controller table delegate methods will be like,

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return list.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SelectionCell") as! OptionsSelectionCell
    cell.titleLabel.text = list[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! OptionsSelectionCell
    cell.checked = !cell.checked
}
}
```

Comment: Ya it's working good, but how I can change interface of it. Because when it's tick the circle is filled, and I have to make it unfilled, as you can see in the image.

Comment: The previous one that I used it was good just it was on the right, not on the left. This one is on the left but it's not looking as is required.

Comment: And also I can't delete cells if I use this.

Comment: If that's what you require, then populate tableview using a custom cell. Handle the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method so as to modify the custom cell to show/hide tick images.
By this way, you will be able to swipe delete cells quite easily.

Comment: Can you explain more in answer ?

Comment: @EminEmini: I have edited my answer in detail. Try this.

Comment: this is all wrong im afraid. making cells show/hide a tick mark on touch is not at all related to editing the tableView

Comment: There is no more relation between table editing and cell selection in the edited code.
And this code will resolve his two problems mentioned in the question.
For deleting cells, he need to implement the tableView delegate methods

Comment: why do you even call setEditing?

Comment: Thats only for the first approach. 
With the second approach, with custom tableviewcell, no need for those two lines in viewDidLoad.
I have edited my answer now.

Comment: Should I make it extension or class ? I tried it, but till now nothing worked.

Comment: Still can't delete cells, and it looks same.

Comment: You shouldn't mess with editing of cell to implement this feature.Maybe this approach works but its still wrong answer